# Problem with Jenkins Jobs Activating Same Conda Environment

Tags: jenkins, anaconda, conda

I have multiple jobs running from the same conda environment. They all `conda activate my_env` before executing a python script.

I currently have 2 jobs that start at the same time, one always fails with:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-31754.tmp.
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-31754.tmp
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

It would seem that the `activate` command in both processes are trying to access the same temp file.

How do I prevent this to allow for parallel execution of scripts against the same conda environment?

Answer (score 0):

This is an [issue with conda](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8628) running on later versions of Windows.

I have a workaround, basically a try/except type loop in the batch file I active conda with:

```
@echo off
:activate_conda
call c:\PATH\TO\CONDA activate ENV_NAME
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto activate_conda
REM do whatever after this line
```